# Stripe Connect Python

Tags: python, django, stripe-connect

Trying to clean this question up a little, everything works in the stripe connect callback function and I can save stripe user id againt my user, Id like to save the stripe user id againt a related profile model but not sure how to get that model from user=request.user. Any suggestions would be a big help.

```
class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    email = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    business_owner = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True) # validators should be a list
    stripe_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)



def stripe_callback(request):
    client_secret = STRIPE_API_KEY
    user = request.user
    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_secret': 'sk_test_5SLLtqWFDTqzdbYmBz4XZpSX',
        'client_id': 'ca_ANdfv3rlKvpOU3rDglk6qoXuBYqGYiq5',
        'code': code,
    } 
    url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
    resp= requests.post(url, params=data)  
    stripe_payload = json.loads(resp.text)
    stripe_user_id = stripe_payload['stripe_user_id']
    user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id 
    user.save()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? It's totally unclear which part of your code isn't working and what you mean by "related profile model"

Comment: No errors, I can save the stripe user id againt my custom user models but i have a profile model where i save extra information against the user, id like to save my stripe id in the users related profile model. I can grab the user from request.user but what id actually like to do is grab the profile model of that user and save the stripe id there.

Comment: Then show us the relevant models. I still don't understand the question. If you have a one-on-one relationship between a `User` and his `Profile`, then you can use `user.profile` to fetch the profile, or not? And if you want to save the `stripe_user_id` to the `Profile`, you need to add that field to the model, so you can do `user.profile.stripe_use_id = stripe_user_id`?

Comment: added the model where id like to save the stripe_user_id return by stripe, which is currently being saved against my CustomUser

Comment: so what doesn't work? `user.company_user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id`?

Comment: I did as suggested by dirkgroten and that resolved it, Thank you.

Comment: note that saving duplicate information in the db can lead to errors later down the road if someone writes code and forgets it's duplicated elsewhere. If stripe_user_id is saved as part of the `CustomUser` model, you can retrieve it also from the `CompanyUser` model: `my_company_user.email.stripe_user_id` (since `email` refers to your `CustomUser`)

Comment: this worked after your suggestion, if you post it as an answer I can accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked so posting incase it may help anyone else, thank you to dirkgroten below in the comments.

```
 def stripe_callback(request):

    client_secret = STRIPE_API_KEY
    # the temporary code returned from stripe
    user = request.user.companyuser
    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    # identify what we are going to ask for from stripe
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_secret': 'sk_test_secretstuff',
        'client_id': 'ca_secretstuff',
        'code': code,
    }
    # Get the access_token using the code provided
    url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
    resp= requests.post(url, params=data)

    stripe_payload = json.loads(resp.text)

    print(stripe_payload)

    stripe_user_id = stripe_payload['stripe_user_id']

    user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id
    print(stripe_user_id)
    user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks dirkgroten!